# Потеря библиотеки

Tags: java

Ситуация следующая:
Я делаю запрос в терминале Windows.
И пробую прочитать ответ.

```
String data = "нечто";
InputStream tr = null;
try {
    tr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(data).getInputStream();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    new ErrorDialog().uncaughtException(ex);
    Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
try {
    if(tr == null)return;
    data = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(tr), "CP866");
```

Приложение пакуется в exe с помощью Launch4j используя локальную копию jre8.
У себя тестировал - все нормально. А вот у пользователя творится следующее:

```
    ...
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils
    at beholder.controllers.newInterface.MainController.initPingTester(MainController.java:256)
    at beholder.controllers.newInterface.MainController.logIn(MainController.java:124)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 58 more
```

Библиотека лежит рядом, я прям ее вижу.

Comment: Может быть у вас в переменных окружения прописан CLASSPATH содержащий `.`, а у пользователя он вообще не прописан?

Comment: Можно попробовать собрать jar со всеми зависимостями, и потом уже его переконвертировать launch4j в exe или что там у вас.